# Flexible query is working For HANA DB but not working in HSQL DB

Tags: java, hsqldb, sap-commerce-cloud, hana

I have the below flexible search query

```
 Select {vt:code},{vt:productcode},{vw:code},{vw:productcode} from {abcd AS vt JOIN wxyz AS vw ON {vt:imeinumber} = {vw:ssnout} } where {vt:productcode} != {vw:productcode}
```

In my  local system the Data base is HSQL so the query is not working and staying in waiting condition where as in cloud server the database is HANA so there it is working perfectly and giving exact result.

Answer (score 1):

The query takes a long time to run probably because there is no index on the join column `ssnout`.

You can create an index with a statement like the one blow, using the correct table and column names.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ssnout ON WZYZ(SSNOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT {vt.code},{vt.productcode},{vw.code},{vw.productcode} 

FROM 
{
  abcd AS vt JOIN wxyz AS vw ON {vt.imeinumber} = {vw.ssnout} 
} 
WHERE {vt.productcode} != {vw.productcode}
```

Comment: Sorry While Posting I have written INNER JOIN , but I am trying with JOIN only. One more thing is both the tables have a huge record, 1 table having around 57k records and the other one having around 20k records.

Comment: are you getting any error when you run this query from HAC?

Comment: Yes I have Tried the above query. The concern is now the time is taking by the query to execute, its around 25-30 minuits, where as in hana its giving the result in 10ms(milliseconds) .

Comment: So now syntax is correct. It will take more time in the local environment compare to you cloud setup, which depends on many factors.

Comment: You can ask a new question with the exact use case, so someone could point you better query or solution.